# REST Assured JSON validation for response without a JSON scheme

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured

I want to check that JSON response at least just valid and cannot find the right way to do this with REST Assured.

I read a lot about `matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath` in [REST Assured examples](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#example-1---json) but I don't want to write the whole JSON schema yet.

```
get("/products").
    then().
    assertThat().
    body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("products-schema.json"));
```

Without add that check any check with malformed JSON was *passed* - so even JSON is not valid I can check field values, or, for example an array size.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.get;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;


public class RestEndpointTest{
    @Test
    public void basic_rest_check() {
        get("/my_endpoint").
            then().
            assertThat().
            body("size()", is(2)).
            statusCode(200);
    }
}
```

And test passed even for the response:

```
[{},{}]MALFORMED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's trivial but I found that only after few days in stuck before I've asked my question. So the solution is using `matchesJsonSchema` instead `matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath`.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.get;
import static io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchema;

public class RestEndpointTest{
    @Test
    public void basic_rest_check() {
        get("/my_endpoint").
            then().
            assertThat().
            body(matchesJsonSchema("{}")).
            statusCode(200);
    }
}
```

Explanation: regarding to http://json-schema.org/

> The most basic schema is a blank JSON object, which constrains
>   nothing, allows anything, and describes nothing:
>
> `{}`

Also there is an option to create file with that content `{}` and load it by `matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath`